# Get a href from xml file into a flash button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a flash file where I'm trying to change the value of the same button depending on the image that is clicked but I can't make it work with different values (I can only make it work with a static value).

AS:

```
var weblinkXML:XML = new XML();
weblinkXML.ignoreWhite = true;
weblinkXML.load("xml/main.xml");
weblinkXML.onLoad = function(success) {
    trace("success = "+success);
for (var i:Number = 0; i< weblinkXML.childNodes.length; i++) {
PPTBUTTON.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_1);
        function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_1(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("test/test.html"), "_blank");
        }
    }
}
```

my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<content>
    <!-- general vars -->
    <settings>
        <item name="copyright"><![CDATA[<font letterspacing="0.5">© 2012 | <a href="event:privacy,0">PRIVACY POLICY</a></font>]]></item>
        <item name="companyName"><![CDATA[<font letterspacing="-2"><b>TANITA</b></font>]]></item>
        <item name="companySlogan"><![CDATA[<font letterspacing="1">PHOTO PORTFOLIO</font>]]></item>
        <!--mp3Url srcUrl="music.mp3"/-->
        <imagesPage>
            <image imageUrl="images/tfile_splash_pic_main.jpg" />
        </imagesPage>
    </settings>

    <!-- menu -->
        <menu>
            <button><![CDATA[PORTFOLIO]]></button>  
            <button><![CDATA[ABOUT]]></button>  
            <button><![CDATA[NEWS]]></button>   
            <button><![CDATA[CONTACTS]]></button>   
        </menu>

        <gallery gallName="Crystal Cabin Awards 2012">
            <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_01.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_01.jpg" buttonName="PPTBUTTON" targ="_self" href="http://www.google.com"/>
        <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_02.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_02.jpg" buttonName="PPTBUTTON" targ="_self" href="http://www.youtube.com"/>
        <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_03.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_03.jpg" buttonName="PPTBUTTON" targ="_self" href="http://www.yahoo.com"/>
            <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_04.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_04.jpg"/>
            <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_05.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_05.jpg"/>
            <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_06.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_06.jpg"/>
            <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_07.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_07.jpg"/>
            <image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_08.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_08.jpg"/>
        </gallery>
```

I realize my xml is complex but it's being used through the entire flash. Maybe I could reduce it to a stand alone xml just like:

```
<image imageUrl="gallery/tfile_gall_small_02.jpg" imagesBig="gallery/tfile_gall_big_02.jpg" buttonName="PPTBUTTON" targ="_self" href="http://www.youtube.com"/>
```

my issue is that I've tried to get the href into a variable and use it instead of "test/test.html" but it never works.

I also realize I have a method inside a for but at this point I've iterated so much over this code that I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: your xml is invalid: `<content>` doesn't have a closing tag. Is this a copy/paste issue ?

Comment: nope I just pasted part of the xml, the rest isn't relevant to this issue. Actually the main issue is inside the <gallery> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how i would retrieve the list of `href` attributes:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xml/main.xml");
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function errorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("Error loading XML" + event.type);
});
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {
    trace("success = " + event);
    var xml:XML = new XML(loader.data);
    var xmllist:XMLList = xml.gallery.children();
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < xmllist.length(); i++) {
        trace(XML(xmllist[i]).attribute("href"));
    }
});
loader.load(request);
```

I had the following output:

```
success = [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
http://www.google.com
http://www.youtube.com
http://www.yahoo.com
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: this answer is awesome I almost got it thanks to this, could you help me at the very end? what I did was save all the urls in an array and then I just want to get the right url depending on which parent image was clicked.

I've looked through the file and gotten this to get the length of the image gallery `MovieClip(root).program.websiteXML.gallery[MovieClip(root).gallery_category_num].image.length()` can I modify that to get the current image idex? I tried `image.attribute.id`, `image.index`, wrapping it in XML like you but nothing so far =/

Comment: i don't understand: so you have 8 images and each one corresponds to an element in your xml ? how do you create those images ? if you create your images dynamically you can bind a `click` event to navigate to your url while creating them.

Comment: The thing is, I was given a template and I'm trying to figure it out. The images are created dynamically BUT the same button is placed on top of them and that same button instance has to take me to different URL's. My intention was to figure out which was the parent image and bind that to the url. So if I do `MovieClip(root).program.websiteXML.gallery[MovieClip(root).gallery_category_num].image`I get the xml of the 8 images but I need the id of the clicked one, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: You're welcome :) When you click on an image, keep its `src` in a variable. Then you can loop into your XMLlist (as I did in my example), and when the attribute `imageUrl` matches the `src` you stored earlier, then use the `href` attribute as a target for your Button.. I hope i understood your question.

Comment: As a follow up question, how could I handle if I had more than 1 type of gallery? As you can see I have "gallName" and I was hoping to add more but the way I did the code it doesn't read the extra galleries.

Comment: you can wrap all your galleries with a `<galleries>` tag and all your galleries would be children of your galleries tag element. Repeat above code for every child..